# Error in Implementing SSML in Alexa Skill

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am new to Skill Development. I wanted to test out how i can use SSML in my skill. So i created the following block of code.

```
else if(light == "right"){
pin = "Right";
pinvalue = "HIGH";
speechOutput = {
type:"AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.SSML",
ssml:"<speak>Ok! starting the car. Please make sure you have fasten your    seat belts </speak>"
};
  }
```

And this is how i am calling it

```
   response.ask(speechOutput);
```

when i run and test this particular block of code i get no error, and receive the following response.

```
 "version": "1.0",
 "response": {
 "outputSpeech": {
  "type": "PlainText",
  "text": {
    "type": "AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.SSML",
    "ssml": "<speak>Ok! starting the car. Please make sure you have fasten   your seat belts </speak>"
  }
},
"shouldEndSession": false
},
"sessionAttributes": {}
}
```

The lights associated with this block of code also light up correctly. However when i run the same code in the Service Simulator. The lights still turn on correctly, however, this is what i get as output.

```
     The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid.
```

I tried running rest of the blocks in the Service Simulator, and all of them give the correct response. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
speechOutput = {
type:"AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.SSML",
ssml:"<speak>Ok! starting the car. Please make sure you have fasten your    seat belts </speak>"
};
```

Note that you probably meant to reference an attribute "AlexaSkill.speechOutputType.SSML", rather then making that a string literal.  So remove the quotes.

Comment: Are you sure?  Cause your Q is about your SSML not working and I'm pretty sure that is not the right way to specify SSML.  It should just be "SSML".  I really think you gotta change it.